# class method as hash value

Tags: ruby

I have this working code:

```
class Server
  def handle(&block)
    @block = block
  end

 def do
   @block.call
 end
end

class Client
  def initialize
    @server = Server.new
    @server.handle { action }
  end

  def action
    puts "some"
  end

  def call_server
    @server.do
  end
end

client = Client.new
client.call_server
```

My Server will handle more then one action so I want to change code such way:

```
class Server
  def handle(options)
    @block = options[:on_filter]
 end

 def do
   @block.call
 end
end

class Client
  def initialize
    @server = Server.new

   my_hash = { :on_filter => action }
   @server.handle(my_hash)
  end

  def action
    puts "some"
  end

  def call_server
    @server.do
  end
end

client = Client.new
client.call_server
```

It is incorrect code because action() method calls on create my_hash, but if I try to modify code to:

```
my_hash = { :on_filter => { action } }
```

i get error message.

Is it possible to create hash with methods as hash values ?

Answer (score 1):

When you want a method, in Ruby, you have to call... `method` :-)

```
my_hash = { :on_filter => { method(:action) } }
```

Note that your original code could have been written:

```
@server.handle(&method(:action))
```

This tells it to use the method `action` as the block parameter (which is why there is a `&`). Instead, you were passing a block, so to be completely equivalent, you can now pass a block instead of a method if you prefer:

```
my_hash = { :on_filter => Proc.new{ action } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, but not exactly with methods (as methods aren't objects in Ruby), but with `Proc` objects instead. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2009/02/ruby-proc.html), for example.

In short, you should be able to achieve what you want by

```
my_hash = { :on_filter => Proc.new{action} }
```

in your `Client#initialize`.

Comment: Methods sure are objects, they have a whole class for them! Actually, two of them: Method, UnboundMethod. Check my answer

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that: http://www.mentby.com/david-a-black/are-methods-objects.html But you're right, `method` method can be useful as well.

Comment: He states that they are not "first class object", whatever that means. He might have a definition for that, but I don't.

The argument with `object_id` simply shows that methods are not immediates (like symbols, true, ...). But neither are floats, strings, Procs, etc...

Methods can be seen as an UnboundMethod with a bound receiver. That doesn't make them less of an object. In Ruby: `42.method(:to_s).is_a?(Object)  # => true`

Comment: I just think that the fact that an object is an instance of class `Method` doesn't make it a method. :) One can say that it's a method wrapped, or a method referenced, but not a method itself.

Comment: I took the liberty to open a question, as this intrigues me a lot, I hope you don't mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602340/methods-in-ruby-objects-or-not